# Vox populi flag vs daily limit of votes

Tags: support, badges

"Next badge" section of my profile shows that I have 36/40 needed votes today to get "Vox Populi" ("Use the maximum 40 votes in a day"). However when I'm trying to vote on any post or answer it's saying "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 2 hours".

Why the discrepancy and I can't vote four more times? Am I lacking some privileges or could it be a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commonly because all votes are not created equal. The system is designed to favor votes on questions, and the [simplest way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/324097) I have seen it explained is that

> 1. Everyone gets a total of 30 votes.
> 2. You may get up to 10 extra question votes.
> 3. Warnings remain simple... (5 votes remaining, 4 votes remaining...)
> 4. Question votes may be cast at any time during the day. However, once you reach the N votes remaining warnings, stuff is set in stone. A question voting spree at the end will still count down.  [[sez waffles]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174/waffles)

Put another way, [Shog9's formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279732/255554) offers that the number of total votes you can cast on a day is

> min( 30 + ⌊1.2×*Q*<sub>25</sub>⌋, 40 )

where *Q*<sub>25</sub> is the number of question votes amongst your first 25 votes and ⌊⌋ denotes rounding down.

For complete details, see *[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212)* at MSE.

Votes on deleted posts do not count toward your daily total, thus *[How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172)*

Comment: I think it’s very clear, if not entirely correct.